# Declaring filter in application in Yii framework

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

In Yii [doc](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-filters#using-filters), it is said that

> Besides controllers, you can also declare filters in a module or application.

But, how to implement that in application, programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach behavior for application in its config.
For example attaching `ContentNegotiator` in your `frontend\config\main.php`:

```php
return [
    'as contentNegotiator' => [
        'class' => \yii\filters\ContentNegotiator::class,
        'formats' => [
            'application/json' => \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
            'application/xml' => \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_XML,
        ],
        'languages' => [
            'en-US',
            'de',
        ],
    ],
    // ... other configuration ...
];
```

Comment: Thanks. I found the doc too. https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-configurations#configuration-format